# convert subsection of a string to int c++

Tags: c++, string, int

I have a string that looks like the following:

Horizontal Binning:           4

I have the whole line stored as a string, and can access the number 4 using something like linestring[30], where linestring is the string the whole line is stored as. I am trying to access the number 4 as an integer, and not a string. How can I do this? I have tried to use atoi(linestring[30].c_str()); but this does not like having an argument to linestring. I cannot use external libraries such as boost etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `substr` instead of `operator[]`. It will give you another `std::string`, not a `char`. Then use `std::stoi` to convert the string to an integer.

Alternatively, use the `char` returned from `operator[]` to create a new `std::string` on which to apply `std::stoi`.

In pre-C++11, use `std::istringstream` instead of `std::stoi`.

By the way, stay away from `atoi`. It makes error checking impossible if `"0"` should be valid input.

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic approach, where you have pairs in the form:

```
foo: <number>
```

You can use something like this:

```
std::string s = "Horizontal Binning: 4";

size_t pos = s.find_last_of(':');
if(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    int num;
    std::stringstream(s.erase(0, pos + 1)) >> num;
    std::cout << "num = " << num << std::endl;
}
else // give error here
```

Comment: `find_last_of` would probably be better here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int value = atoi(linestring.c_str() + 30);
```

but you must be sure that the string is at least 30 chars, otherwise this would imply undefined behavior.

Comment: perfect, I should have read up more on the atoi command first. thanks

Comment: This will not work if the input is `"Horizontal Binning: 0"` and error checking should detect wrong input like `"Horizontal Binning: x"`, because `atoi` returns 0 for conversion errors. So there's no way to distinguish between a valid zero and a zero caused by a conversion error.

Comment: this is acceptable since binning is always a value > 0

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how long the text before the number is, you could simply loop until you find a digit and call atoi from there :

```
auto it = begin(str);
while (it != end(str) && !isdigit(*it))
    ++it;
cout << atoi(&*it) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is C++ and you're working with an `std::string`, use [`stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) instead of `atoi`. Here's a generic solution inspired by [Innocent Bystander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4358570/innocent-bystander)'s answer.

To find the position of `:` in the string and parse the int after that:

```
size_t start = linestring.find_last_of(':') + 1;
int i = std::stoi(linestring.substr(start));
```

You could even make that into a one-liner.

---

Or if you know the number will always be only one digit, and it's the last char in the string:

```
int i = linestring.back() - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `sscanf` which tries to match a pattern:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

void Extract(const std::string& s) {
    int value = 0;
    int r = sscanf(s.c_str(), "Horizontal Binning: %d", &value);
    if (r == 1) {
        printf("value is %d\n", value);
    } else {
        printf("cannot extract value\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    Extract("Horizontal Binning: 4");
    Extract("Whatever: 4");
}
```

The output is:

```
value is 4
cannot extract value
```